# Telegram Bots - inline mode

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to use a bot in inline mode and I'm using a java opensource library to handle RESTful request to the telegram API. The library can be found at this link https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api. I tried to do this:

```
String query = inlineQuery.query().trim().toLowerCase();
List<String> answerList = new LinkedList<String>();
answerList.add("first_answer");
answerList.add("second_answer");
InlineQueryResult[] resArray = new InlineQueryResult[answerList.size()];
for (int j = 0; j < resArray.length; j++)}{ 
    resArray[j] = new InlineQueryResultArticle(inlineQuery.id(), answerList.get(j), query);
}
bot.answerInlineQuery(inlineQuery.id(), resArray);
```

but I have this exception at runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request
```

---

I edited the first parameter of the `InlineQueryResultArticle` constructor from `inlineQuery.id()` to `"id_"+j` and now it works.

Comment: Did you go through the steps creating a token using Botfather? Is your code using that token? https://core.telegram.org/bots#6-botfather

Comment: Yes, these steps are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 2.0.0 version of library. 
Now error message is returned in response object. 
And there are an API changes

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the new version of library and I have the following description of the response:

`Bad Request: RESULT_ID_DUPLICATE`

I replaced the last code line with `BaseResponse response = bot.execute(new AnswerInlineQuery(inlineQuery.id(), resArray));`

Comment: @chris You should use unique id for `InlineQueryResultArticle` like `new InlineQueryResultArticle(j, answerList.get(j), query);`